# Rust Iron Web Framework gives some phantom error

Tags: rust, iron

I am using iron. Most of time like 99.* % all is good. But sometimes I get error like Error was: ErrorImpl { code: EofWhileParsingString/List/Object, line: 1, column: 8186 } or  InvalidUnicodeCodePoint. I am printing request in log and when i try that request every thing goes well. I also have server written in Golang receiving same request and they never have parsing or json to MyStruct conversion problem.**Please note Code would not compile as it is, missing imports, error::from and structure definition. Can not provide reproducible request logs as it only happens when serving lots on concurrent request but if single request is taken it works fine.** 
I have tried serde_json::from_reader, bodyparser crate and all have same issue.

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate iron;
use self::iron;
use self::iron::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {

}
struct ResponseTime;
impl typemap::Key for ResponseTime {
    type Value = u64;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RequestBody;
impl typemap::Key for RequestBody {
    type Value = RefCell<Vec<u8>>;
}

impl BeforeMiddleware for ResponseTime {
    fn before(&self, req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<()> {
        req.extensions.insert::<RequestBody>(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));
        req.extensions.insert::<ResponseTime>(precise_time_ns());
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl AfterMiddleware for ResponseTime {
    fn after(&self, req: &mut Request, res: Response) -> IronResult<Response> {
         Ok(res)
    }
    fn catch(&self, req : &mut Request, err : IronError) -> IronResult<Response> {
        let ref byte_req = *req.extensions.get::<RequestBody>()
                        .unwrap()
                        .borrow();
        //just to make sure uft8 is not causing some issue. 
        let payload  = unsafe {
            str::from_utf8_unchecked(&byte_req)
        };
        //but when i send request body all comes good
        error!("Error {} for Body {}", err, payload);
        Err(err)
    }
}


fn iron_handler(req : &mut Request) -> Result<Response, CustomError>{
    let mut buffer = req.extensions.get::<server::RequestBody>()
                        .unwrap()
                        .borrow_mut();
    req.body.read_to_end(&mut buffer)?;
    // not seeing InvalidUnicodeCodePoint after this. 
    let payload = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer);
    //some request throw error
    let my_struct_obj : MyStruct = serde_json::from_str(&payload)?;
    Ok(Response::with((iron::status::Ok, "Final Response")))
}
```

Need help to figure out how to identify problem. **Intent of posting here is to see if someone had same issue or can see obvious problem with this.** Appreciate everyone'e time do not expect to build and run with examples as can not provide them because of privacy.

Comment: The code presented is not even syntactically valid — the function `after` is missing the definition.

Comment: @Shepmaster that is correct. Corrected it.

Comment: Attempting to compile this code in a clean cargo project, adding all the crates specified by `extern crate` (e.g. none), produces **25 compilation errors**. Please review how to create a [MCVE]. For example, you state "parsing or json to MyStruct" but *never define what `MyStruct` is*.

Comment: @Shepmaster i can take down this question if not following forum norm. Intent here is to see if someone else has faced this issue when running with lots of concurrent request (not simply ab or wrk tools) or one can see obvious bug.

Comment: *do not expect to build and run with examples as can not provide them because of privacy.* — We don't want your *real* code, we want the simplest possible piece of code that reproduces the same errors you are seeing. It is unlikely to have much in common with the original code that experienced the problem. You should have already created this in an attempt to debug your own problem. *or one can see obvious bug* — how can we see a bug in code that hasn't been provided?

Comment: @Shepmaster in process of debugging i did print payload in catch block. I also printed only bytes without converting to str. Both seems to result in correct data. Missing code is call to different service which further processes the request. But bug comes from code provided and I know because i did my debugging.